# Curator Elastic Search is Free or License

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am not getting proper information that that the Curator Elastic Search is Free or License ?

Could anybody let me know ? it would helpful if anybody could share a link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic curator has a apache license 2.0.

Here is the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/license.html

Also read what you are allowed to do and what not here 
https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Another good link
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56927/what-are-the-real-life-implications-for-an-apache-2-license

Comment: Thanks.. I m just confusing about this line in doc "you may not use this file except in compliance with the License" is that mean this is apache licence & what i have to do if I use this in production

Comment: read the license and see what it allows. what are you planning to use it btw?

Comment: I m just planning to use the curator tool on production to delete indices from elasticsearch... yes but do I need to provide anything or just I can download curator tool and keep it on server and say delete command of curator ? will it be fine ?

Comment: I have gone through doc ... then I have downloaded curator from site(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/installation.html) now In curator folder I can see the licence.txt with apache... So If I have to use on my production then I will have to keep licence.txt file same as it ?? right ? Please clear my doubt ....

Comment: Thanks buddy. I got my answer from apache site as well question 6 & 7 http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#Marks